# Getting error while running SonarScannerMSBuild on Xamarin projects

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, sonarqube, sonarscanner

**1)  When I Try to use Rebuild option**

MANOJs-MacBook-Air:UI_Testing2 manojdeshpande$ mono /Users/manojdeshpande/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.5.0.1761-net46/MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe /t:Rebuild

WARNING: ------------------------------------------------------------------------

This executable is deprecated and may be removed in next major version of the SonarScanner for MSBuild. Please use 'SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe' instead.

---

SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.5

Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild

Default properties file was found at /Users/manojdeshpande/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.5.0.1761-net46/SonarQube.Analysis.xml

Loading analysis properties from /Users/manojdeshpande/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.5.0.1761-net46/SonarQube.Analysis.xml

WARNING: Please specify the command 'begin' or 'end' to indicate whether pre- or post-processing is required. These parameters will become mandatory in a later release.

Pre-processing started.

Preparing working directories...

05:23:39.463  05:23:39.454  Unrecognized command line argument: /t:Rebuild

05:23:39.464  05:23:39.462  A required argument is missing: /key:[SonarQube project key]

05:23:39.464  Expecting at least the following command line argument:

- SonarQube project key

When connecting to a SonarQube server earlier than version 6.1, the following command line arguments are also required:

- SonarQube project name
- SonarQube project version

The full path to a settings file can also be supplied. If it is not supplied, the exe will attempt to locate a default settings file in the same directory as the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild.

Use '/?' or '/h' to see the help message.

05:23:39.464  Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1

**2)  I get some other error with authentication problems. Any work around this.**

MANOJs-MacBook-Air:UI_Testing2 manojdeshpande$ mono /Users/manojdeshpande/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.5.0.1761-net46/SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"Xamarin" /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000" /d:sonar.login="token1"

SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.5

Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild

Default properties file was found at /Users/manojdeshpande/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.5.0.1761-net46/SonarQube.Analysis.xml

Loading analysis properties from /Users/manojdeshpande/Downloads/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.5.0.1761-net46/SonarQube.Analysis.xml

Pre-processing started.

Preparing working directories...

05:18:52.798  Updating build integration targets...

05:18:52.833  Fetching analysis configuration settings...

05:18:52.94  Failed to request and parse 'http://localhost:9000/api/settings/values?component=Xamarin': The remote server returned an error: (401) .

05:18:52.94  Could not authorize while connecting to the SonarQube server. Check your credentials and try again.

05:18:52.941  Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1

Comment: Is this a new setup / first project? What SonarQube version / plugins do you use? What do you see if you try to open localhost:9000?

Comment: Hello sir....yes it is first project, I am using "sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.4.2.1543-net46" version for sonar-scanner for MSBuild and using Sonarqube as docker service in localhost. I am seeing 0 errors, 0 vulnerabilities and 0 warnings in localhost:9000. Thanks